# Updating IIS SSL Settings, Client Certificates: IGNORE, ACCEPT, REQUIRE. APPCMD

Tags: ssl, iis, client-certificates, appcmd

Trying to update the Client certificate settings inside of IIS using AppCMD

Managed to update the check box for "Require SSL" through the below command:

appcmd.exe set config "Website/virtual application" -section:system.webServer/ security/access /sslFlags:"Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" /commit:apphost

However, the second section which is "Client Certificates" in IIS I am unable to set and it keeps being set to "Accept" I would like to set it to "Ignore"

I cant use Powershell to complete this.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I has to use the option SSL and that has worked

sslFlags:"Ssl, None"

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction